Problems customizing locale in Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS
Based on the excellent instructions in this thread, I have created a custom locale, en_CH by combining entries from de_CH and en_US. The one thing I am trying to do differently is to get dates and times in ISO / 24 hour format.  I have tried many variations in LC_TIME, but I always wind up with dates in either U.S. or U.K. format.
Here is the relevant part of my current LC_TIME section:
% Appropriate date and time representation (%c)
d_t_fmt  "%F %T"
% Appropriate date and time representation for date(1).  This is
% different from d_t_fmt for historical reasons and has been different
% since 2000 when date_fmt was added as a GNU extension.  At the end
% of 2018 it was adjusted to use 12H time (bug 24046) instead of 24H.
date_fmt "%a %x %X %Z"
% Appropriate date representation (%x)
d_fmt   "%Y-%m-%d"
% Appropriate time representation (%X)
t_fmt   "%H:%M:%S"
am_pm   "";""
% Appropriate AM/PM time representation (%r)
t_fmt_ampm ""

When I select en_CH for the other sections in the Region & Language settings, the results are as expected. In the Region & Language settings I found en_SE.  This seems to produce the results I want for date and time formats, but there is no corresponding file in /usr/share/i18n/locales/, nor do I find such a locale listed at https://lh.2xlibre.net/locales/.
What could be overriding the LC_TIME settings in my en_CH locale?
Where does the en_SE locale come from?
P.S. Executing "locale -k LC_TIME" delivers the following:
am_pm=";"
d_t_fmt="%F %T"
d_fmt="%Y-%m-%d"
t_fmt="%H:%M:%S"
t_fmt_ampm=""

which seems to indicate that my settings are being loaded, yet both Krusader and the system tray display the date in  U.K. format.
P.P.S.
So I went ahead and used en_SE for time format, which gives me ISO dates. Then I ran "locale -k LC_TIME" again to see how it was done. Here are the (excerpted) results:
d_t_fmt="%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y"
d_fmt="%m/%d/%y"
t_fmt="%H:%M:%S"
t_fmt_ampm="%I:%M:%S %p"
date_fmt="%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"

Here d_fmt is in U.K. format, yet I see ISO date format in both the system tray and in Krusader.  How can this be?
